# Oracle out-of-place upgrade on same host: impdp issues

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, datapump

I am testing an out-of-place Oracle upgrade from 11.2.0.2 to 11.2.0.3 on the same host. From what I've read, expdp and impdp is the way to go. My problem is that since I am importing to another instance on the same host, it's trying to recreate the same directory structures. The beginning of the import log looks like this:

```
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  system/********@NEWINSTANCE full=Y directory=bak_dir 

dumpfile=dbexp.dmp 
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TABLESPACE
ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"SYSAUX" already exists
ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"UNDOTBS1" already exists
ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"TEMP" already exists
ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"USERS" already exists
ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE failed to create with error:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\DB1\TBLSP_73_DATA.DBF'
ORA-27038: created file already exists
OSD-04010: <create> option specified, file already exists
Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLESPACE "TBLSP_73_DATA" DATAFILE 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\DB1\TBLSP_73_DATA.DBF' SIZE 104857600 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 52428800 MAXSIZE 32767M LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192 EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS  SEGMENT
```

It appears that it's attempting to use the same paths as the source database. How can I get the datapump import to point to a new path like D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\DB2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Oracle Utilities documentation.  When using Datapump tools, you can reset paths using the REMAP_DATAFILE parameter for import jobs.

Also, insure your OS session variables reflect the new DB.  This is often over-looked when working with a new DB on a server that already has a DB working on it.

Comment: REMAP_DATAFILE works, I found that solution but it took me a while to get the quoting/delimiting syntax correct. Can you expand on the session variables? I'm also having an issue with roles not importing, seemingly due to the fact that the object already exists.

Comment: Can you post the solution that works?